# ListView Overflow Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-listview

I want my ListView to not overlap with the other elements.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TWwq.png)

Here's my code, I hope you guys can help me solve my problem. Thank you.

```
 
      return AlertDialog(
        surfaceTintColor: colors.background,
        contentPadding:
            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 24),
        insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
        content: SizedBox(
          height: screenSize.height - 125,
          width: screenSize.width,
          child: Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Saved Addresses',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge?.copyWith(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SavedLocationsListWidget(),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 44,
                    child: UtolButtonIcon(
                      colors: colors.secondary,
                      label: Text(
                        'Cancel',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge?.copyWith(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                      ),
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.close_fullscreen_outlined,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 20,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ], // Button
```

I tried using SizedBox but the List disappears.
wrapping them in Padding does not work also

Comment: don't get it. How overlap? Can you draw/point at your picture?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What have you tried and what do you exactly want?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, as you can see in the photo, The List Tile is scrolling waypast my titlescreen and the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
return AlertDialog(
              contentPadding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 24),
              insetPadding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
              content: SizedBox(
                  height: screenSize.height - 125,
                  width: screenSize.width,
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Saved Addresses',
                            style: Theme.of(c).textTheme.labelLarge?.copyWith(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Expanded(
                          child: ListView.separated(
                              separatorBuilder: (c, i) =>
                                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                              itemCount: 25,
                              itemBuilder: (c, i) {
                                return DecoratedBox(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border.all(
                                          color: Colors.indigo, width: 1),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                    ),
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      title: Text('Item ${i + 1}'),
                                    ));
                              }),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: 44,
                            child: TextButton.icon(
                              label: Text(
                                'Cancel',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.indigo,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              icon: const Icon(
                                Icons.close_fullscreen_outlined,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: 20,
                              ),
                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(c).pop();
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ])));
```